# Simulating graphene-based antenna using HFSS

Tags: antenna

Recently, I am learning to simulate the graphene-based antenna using HFSS software. There are some issues I did not figure out.

According to my understanding, since there is no graphene material defined in the HFSS software, we need to define the material ourselves in the HFSS software. From the Kubo formula or Drude model, the complex conductivity of the graphene can be calculated, which is frequency dependent. However, in HFSS, the properties to define material only allows real values for all the items as shown below, so may I know how to map the complex conductivity to the items in the bellowing HFSS table. Or are there other ways to define the graphene material in HFSS?

Thank you guys in advance.
[image: HFSS snapshot]

Answer (score 3):

The **loss** **tangent** settings allow to define the angle of the (complex) permeability/permittivity.